# Spring boot - @ConditionalOnProperty or @ConditionalOnExpression

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring-Boot-1.1.7.
My intention is to add a bean to my context according to a value of a property of type string.

I mean, I can see a lot of examples of boolean values such as this:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${xxx.enabled:true}")
```

But I want an expression based on a value of a property, for example:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${server.host==localhost} or ${server.port==8080} ")
```

or something like that.

Can someone show me an example how to do it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Eventually , this one worked for me:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${server.host}'=='localhost'")
```

Comment: Yeah that would work (obvious really). You are comparing 2 literals.

Comment: Just to confirm, even though its quoted, ${server.host} is resolved correctly? So if server.host is 'foobar', the expression is evaluated as 'foobar'=='localhost'?

Comment: Yes it is, and the evaluation is performed correctly, only if you quote it.

Answer (score 36):

For property value conditional I used:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="server.host", havingValue="localhost")
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value you want to compare with is a literal, you need to quote it, and the placeholder would go round the property name (not the whole expression), e.g. `${server.host}=='localhost'`

Comment: Placing your example ended with this exception: ' Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'localhost' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext ' - maybe not public?' I added the expression that work (surprisingly, I must say) at the below answer.Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using e.g. a string value and want to check if **a value** is set, you can use a simple "check":

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "foo.value")
public class Foo {
    private String value;
    // getter/ setter and other stuff ...
}
```

If you add: `foo.value: bar` to your `application.yml` file the component will be found and added to the application context, but if you do **not** set a value the component will not be added.

If you want to check if the component is found, you can use: `debug: true` in your `application.yml`.

```
Foo matched:
- @ConditionalOnProperty (foo.value) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```

vs

```
Foo: Did not match:
- @ConditionalOnProperty (foo.value) did not find property 'foo.value' (OnPropertyCondition)
```